# Is there any way to capture live video using webcam in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I saw a way provided by colab team to capture a the image over colab but is there any way to capture the video there?

Answer (score 6):

Recently came across this post as I was searching for the answer too. I ended up having to write my own snippet, as I couldn't find anything. Here's what I ended up with in case this helps. The code is broken out into two separate cells. I'm using `Python 3` and `Google Chrome`:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64decode

def record_video(filename='video.mp4'):

  # This function uses the take_photo() function provided by the Colab team as a  
  # starting point, along with a bunch of stuff from Stack overflow, and some sample code 
  # from: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

  js = Javascript("""
    async function recordVideo() {
      const options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      const capture = document.createElement('button');
      const stopCapture = document.createElement("button");
      capture.textContent = "Start Recording";
      capture.style.background = "green";
      capture.style.color = "white";

      stopCapture.textContent = "Stop Recording";
      stopCapture.style.background = "red";
      stopCapture.style.color = "white";
      div.appendChild(capture);

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      const recordingVid = document.createElement("video");
      video.style.display = 'block';

      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
      let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        capture.onclick = resolve;
      });
      recorder.start();
      capture.replaceWith(stopCapture);
      await new Promise((resolve) => stopCapture.onclick = resolve);
      recorder.stop();

      let recData = await new Promise((resolve) => recorder.ondataavailable = resolve);
      let arrBuff = await recData.data.arrayBuffer();
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();

      let binaryString = "";
      let bytes = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
      bytes.forEach((byte) => {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(byte);
      })
      return btoa(binaryString);
    }
    """)
  try:
    display(js)
    data = eval_js('recordVideo({})')
    binary = b64decode(data)
    with open(filename, "wb") as video_file:
      video_file.write(binary)
    print(
        f"Finished recording video. Saved binary under filename in current working directory: {filename}"
    )
  except Exception as err:
      # In case any exceptions arise
      print(str(err))
  return filename
```

```py
# Run the function, get the video path as saved in your notebook, and play it back here.
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode

video_width = 300

video_path = record_video()
video_file = open(video_path, "r+b").read()

video_url = f"data:video/mp4;base64,{b64encode(video_file).decode()}"
HTML(f"""<video width={video_width} controls><source src="{video_url}"></video>""")
```

And here's a link to the notebook: https://github.com/emilyxxie/colab_utils_and_snippets/blob/master/video_webcam_snippets.ipynb

Comment: This is great! I tried using "const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true, video: true});" in this snippet to also record audio with the video, but it caused a lot of feedback. Any chance you know how to record video and audio?

Comment: @JohnKitchin add `video.muted = true;` before `await video.play();` + your change and the feedback will be gone but still recorded.

Comment: How we can set a particular video length in code like example Once I press start button It should record only 10-sec video then it will automatically stop.