# Google Colab cannot capture webcam videos longer than 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-colaboratory, webcam

I have been trying to set up webcam recording in Google Colab. Through adapting code found here: [Is there any way to capture live video using webcam in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529304/is-there-any-way-to-capture-live-video-using-webcam-in-google-colab?newreg=aae1ba3f976c45969b6d7e8c64bfb771) I was able to get some video, however, if I try to record for more than 60 seconds the environment crashes.

I've tried a few rough workarounds:

- Recording numerous smaller videos and concatenating them. This led to gaps in the footage.
- Calling the 'wait' function a few time... 30 seconds, then another 30 seconds ect. This still led to crashing with anything over 60 seconds.

This work has led me to believe that the problem isn't a timeout, it's caused by the video buffer size being exceeded by the incoming video stream.

I'm new to javascript and realize this isn't really what Colab is made for, but would appreciate any help - even if it's just letting me know that this isn't a feasible thing to do! My code can be found below, thanks in advance!

```
# Run the function, get the video path as saved in your notebook, and play it back here.
from IPython.display import HTML, display, Javascript
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from google.colab.output import eval_js

def record_video_timed(filename='video.mp4'):
  js = Javascript("""
  async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
    async function recordVideo() {
      // mashes together the advanced_outputs.ipynb function provided by Colab, 
      // a bunch of stuff from Stack overflow, and some sample code from:
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

      // Optional frames per second argument.
      const options = { mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9" };
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
      let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
      
      recorder.start();
      await wait(10000);//less than 60 or it crashes
      recorder.stop(); 

      let recData = await new Promise((resolve) => recorder.ondataavailable = resolve);
      let arrBuff = await recData.data.arrayBuffer();
      let binaryString = "";
      let bytes = new Uint8Array(arrBuff);
      bytes.forEach((byte) => {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(byte);
      })
      return btoa(binaryString);
    }
    """)
  try:
    display(js)
    data = eval_js('recordVideo({})')
    binary = b64decode(data)
    with open(filename, "wb") as video_file:
      video_file.write(binary)
    print(
        f"Finished recording video. Saved binary under filename in current working directory: {filename}"
    )
  except Exception as err:
      # In case any exceptions arise
      print(str(err))
  return filename

#######

video_path = record_video_timed()
```